# PHP: references are shared between recursive calls

Tags: php, recursion, reference, pass-by-reference

I’ve got three functions, `foo`, `bar` and `baz`, which, from my point of view, should produce identical results. However, I’m stuck with a problem that references are **shared** between recursive function calls.

```
$array = array(
    'subs' => array(
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
    ),
);

function foo(&$array, $value, $callAgain = true) {
    $subs =& $array['subs'];
    foreach ($subs as &$sub)
        $sub = $value;
    if ($callAgain) {
        $copy = $array;
        foo($copy, $value + 1, false);
    }
}

function bar(&$array, $value, $callAgain = true) {
    foreach ($array['subs'] as &$sub)
        $sub = $value;
    if ($callAgain) {
        $copy = $array;
        bar($copy, $value + 1, false);
    }
}

function baz(&$array, $value, $callAgain = true) {
    foreach ($array['subs'] as $key => $sub)
        $array['subs'][$key] = $value;
    if ($callAgain) {
        $copy = $array;
        baz($copy, $value + 1, false);
    }
}

foo($array, 3);
var_dump($array);
bar($array, 3);
var_dump($array);
baz($array, 3);
var_dump($array);
```

This code produces the following results:

```
array
  'subs' => 
    array
      'a' => int 4
      'b' => int 4
array
  'subs' => 
    array
      'a' => int 3
      'b' => int 4
array
  'subs' => 
    array
      'a' => int 3
      'b' => int 3
```

However, I expect all of them to return `3, 3`, because copies of the array are passed to recursive calls.

How to fix the first two functions to make them return `3, 3`? I’d prefer not to use syntax of the `baz` function, because it’s very verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question-- `baz` IS the way to get the behavior you want.  The other two functions are behaving as intended in PHP, at least according to the manual page on [What References Do](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php):

> Note, however, that references inside arrays are potentially dangerous. Doing a normal (not by reference) assignment with a reference on the right side does not turn the left side into a reference, but references inside arrays are preserved in these normal assignments. This also applies to function calls where the array is passed by value. Example:

```
/* Assignment of array variables */
$arr = array(1);
$a =& $arr[0]; //$a and $arr[0] are in the same reference set
$arr2 = $arr; //not an assignment-by-reference!
$arr2[0]++;
/* $a == 2, $arr == array(2) */
/* The contents of $arr are changed even though it's not a reference! */
?>
```

> In other words, the reference behavior of arrays is defined in an element-by-element basis; the reference behavior of individual elements is dissociated from the reference status of the array container.

Comment: If ANY variable ANYWHERE in the code references ANY value inside the array, I can't rely on copying the array (copy will have references where variables point)? So, the way I see it, I can NEVER reference inside arrays, including using `foreach($a => &$v)`, because it “corrupts” the array so that it can’t be copied properly? Now, that's shocking news.